# Laravel problema al definir rutas

Tags: laravel, rutas

Estoy definiendo las rutas en el archivo `routes/web.php` (uso laravel 5.7).

Normalmente, las defino así:

```
Route::get('url_para_mostrar', Controlador@metodo)->name('nombre_de_ruta');
```

El problema es que tengo varias rutas a métodos que no deben mostrar una vista. Son métodos que se llaman por ajax, para devolver una response con unos datos que son colocados en la vista actual. Empecé por definir las rutas así:

```
Route::get(null, Controlador@metodo)->name('nombre_de_ruta');
```

En el primer parámetro puse `null`, porque como no van a dar lugar a una vista, no es necesario que haya una URL que mostrar. El problema es que cuando tengo más de una ruta así, en enrutador no reconoce el nombre que pongo en el método `name()`, y me lanza una excepción, diciendo que la ruta no existe.

Así que la pregunta es la siguiente: cuando hay rutas que apuntan a métodos que no retornan una vista, cual es el modo adecuado de definirlas? Podría rellenar el primer parámetro con cualquier cosa, ya que nunca se va a mostrar la URL, pero me suena a chapuza. Estoy segura de que hay una forma más adecuada de definir esas rutas. No sé si debería definirlas con una sintaxis específica en `api.php` y, en ese caso, como invocarlas correctamente. Podeis explicarme la forma correcta de hacerlo, al estilo de laravel? Muchas gracias.

Respecto a los comentarios de Shaz, las llamo con un ajax de jquery, así:

`var url = "{{ route('nombre_de_ruta') }}";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        pasajero: $('#pasajeros').val(),
        ciudades: $('#ciudades_disponibles').val(),
        _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    },
    success:function(resultado) {
        console.log (resultado);
    }
});`

No se si te refieres a esto. Es la llamada que tengo en una vista.

Comment: ¿Cómo llamas a esas rutas entonces? me refiero al hacer la solicitud ajax.

Comment: por favor responde mi pregunta para poder darte una mejor explicación que la que te dieron en la respuesta que aceptaste.

Comment: Te puse la llamada por ajax en el cuerpo de la pregunta. No sé si te referías a eso, o hace falta algo más.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para definir rutas para llamadas por AJAX, tienes que definirlas en el archivo `routes/api.php`. Poner NULL el primer parámetro de la ruta no es para no retornar vistas, el primer parámetro es la dirección de la ruta, lo que devuelvas ya depende de lo que hagas en el método.

Si quieres definir una ruta para API, es como las de siempre `Route::get('prueba', 'Controlador@metodo')`. Entonces podrás acceder a esa ruta de la siguiente manera: "my-dominio.com/api/prueba".

Al usar las rutas de api, Laravel por defecto asume que devolverás respuestas en json. Aun así, si necesitas devolver algo que no sea una vista, simplemente en el método que llames, cambia `return view(vista)` por `return response()->json()` para devolver datos en json.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Francisco. Sin embargo, querría pedirte una aclaración. En `api.php` puedo usar el método `name()` para nombrar las rutas? En ese caso, puedo prescindir del primer parámetro en la definición de la ruta? Y otra cosa. Puede haber conflictos por el hecho de que se use el middleware api en lugar de web?
Sí he observado que cuando pongo `return response($datos)`, si `$datos` es una matriz, me lo devuelve directamente en JSON, sin usar el método `json()`. Este método aporta algo específico?
Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Mas que nada el metodo json() es para cuando quieres devolver json sin usar las rutas api, ya que laravel ya asume que vas a devolver un json si usas la api. Si no me equivoco, también puedes usar name para las rutas, pero esto es solo para que laravel vaya a ellas internamente. Si va a ser una API, necesitas una dirección a la que acceder. Y no, no deberia haber conflictos, simplemente si usas web en lugar de api, tendras que usar el metodo json() para devolver json.

Comment: Aclarar: *"Para definir rutas para llamadas por AJAX, tienes que definirlas en el archivo `routes/api.php`"* muy recomendado, pero no obligatorio, es decir, igual van a funcionar en `routes/web.php`.